# When are IT departments considered dominant or near dominant coalitions?

Tags: software-industry, human-resources, technology

After working in four different organizations as a developer or business analyst role, I have noticed that IT departments and IS departments can be considered second-class citizens, even when they produce externally facing, revenue producing products.

**What are some instances in which IT departments have power for strategic influence in a company, beyond being up to date with current technologies?**

By strategic influence, I'm referring to the ability to define what the product is and it's scope, rather than just executing commands from other departments.

Comment: And what product or service is the web site selling?  Is this a company that sells web software.

Comment: Yes, they sell a few software products as a subscription, but that is just one service of many which are non-software related, but are supported by home grown software.

Comment: What is "*strategic influence*" the way you understand it?

Comment: @PM77-1 , I edited in reference to your comment.

Comment: Dominant?  IT is dominant when is is a software company.  And even then IT support will not have power for strategic influence in a company.   Software product as a subscription is a service.

Comment: @Frisbee , thanks but if you want any potential rep, that could qualify as an answer.

Comment: Rarely as most companies will have product development departments that are separate from IT but I'm not sure you understand the distinction here.

Comment: It sounds like you're working in companies where the IT department is a means to an end, rather than the end in itself. Try finding a more focused (probably smaller) company, or one where software development is the core activity. Companies who are trying to sell bread will need IT departments, but that department is there to help them sell bread and will always be second priority.

Comment: @JBKing, but what about business analysts? They usually report to IT.  What if there is no product development department?

Comment: Hi Kyle, I would encourage you to read through [this link](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to see what types of questions are on topic here. The section [here on "don't ask"](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) suggests polling types of questions are not a good fit. Just because there is a question mark does not make a question a good fit for Stack Exchange. Thanks!

Comment: @KyleJV, business analysts are in the IT department as part of the glue between developers and non-technical people in my experience that are usually there to make sure that the business people do specify the requirements enough so developers can get something done that can be accepted. Not sure I'd see that as having the R & D arm that you were seeking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's easy to provide an example. My small company provides specialised and general IT services to other companies and/or govt depts. So I value my techs and programmers much more than I do the sales and admin staff. And some of the services I now provide were actually dreamed up by the IT.

I'm sure there's other examples, in my country, in general even normal IT are treated with the same sort of deference as managers (except amongst themselves)

Answer (score 4):

## When (and only when) they have good leadership.

There are [284 million results for "business versus IT"](https://www.google.com.au/?q=business%20vs%20it#q=business%20versus%20it), so its safe to assume a dichotomy between what constitutes "business" and what constitutes "IT".

Like in all workplaces, people vie for control over pretty much anything, including the product. In some places this falls to "marketing" in some cases it falls to "business" in some place it falls to "IT". In all cases however, it falls under the direction of the individual or area that convinced the head or heads of the company that they are the most capable of leading that charge.

As an employee outside of the management chain there isn't very much you can do to influence it as it is far above your head.

Answer (score 0):

Dominant?  IT is a support organization and is not going to have power for strategic influence in a company, beyond being up to date with current technologies.  IT will vie for budget.  IT support is not the product of the company. As a friend of mine says we are a support organization and prepare to be serviced.

Even if it is a software company IT support will not have strategic influence.  Software development and marketing will decide the direction of the software.

Comment: And therein lies the rub, how a do you divide "IT" and "Software development"? Ask a lot of "business people" and they'd say they are the same thing.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr Rub?  Pretty simple a developer writes software.  So a business person does not know the difference -  does not mean there is not a difference.  A business person is not gong to have IT in a power for strategic influence even if they don't know the difference.  If it is a software company the top business people will know the difference.  Really you think any VP at Microsoft does not know the difference?  A VP at Acme brick may not know the difference and they are not going to ask IT for input on strategic planning.

Comment: IT looks after computers, network infrastructure, and installed software. Software development creates software for use in the company or for external sale/use. To anyone involved directly in either, the delineation is **very** clear. It's the difference between a car manufacturer who builds the car to sell, and a car mechanic who services the car for the new owner to keep it running and get the owner where they need to be.

Comment: @JON Story , unfortunately some companies bundle infrastructure with development in one department, under a CIO

Comment: That's definitely common in larger companies where development is a sideline activity - I was just pointing out the difference for the commenter who asked 'how do you divide them' - not all companies do choose to divide them, but that's the difference